# Grab content of strangely secured webpage

Tags: php

I'm trying to read score sheets from a webpage. In order to create some statistics for our team I want to automatically save the results in my own database. E.g. http://fvbw.sm-u.de/index.php?seite=game&game=568

I tried to get the content of the page via several options in PHP (curl, file, file_get_contents, etc.) but I always come up with a strange behaviour. The actual scores are shown in the `<div id="inhalt"></div>` container when viewed in the browser. But when I get the page via PHP the container is always empty.

My first thought was that the content is reloaded via JS. But I can't find any JS calls! Also Firebug tracks no such activity. There's also no use of the CSS attribute content or anything else.

Can someone tell me what is going on there? And how I'm able to grab the content of that page via PHP?

**Update (2013-03-27 12:05):**

Here is my code that uses the same headers as a request by Firefox. This returns the same incomplete result.

```
$curl = curl_init();
$header[] = "Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8";
$header[] = "Accept-Language: de-de,de;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3";
$header[] = "Accept-Encoding: deflate";
$header[] = "Referer: http://fvbw.sm-u.de/index.php?seite=table&table=15";
$header[] = "Connection: keep-alive";
$header[] = "Cache-Control: max-age=0";
$header[] = "Host: fvbw.sm-u.de";

curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:19.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/19.0");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$data = curl_exe($curl);
```

One more strange thing that's happening. When using HttpRequester (Firefox Addon) I just type the url and execute the request and it gets me the right result. The raw request looks like this

```
GET http://fvbw.sm-u.de/index.php?seite=game&game=571
```

No headers, no nothing. If I do this using curl I still get the incomplete page.

Comment: Make sure that a single HTTP request is returning the content you want by using your browser's development tools. Then write code that exactly duplicates that HTTP request using `curl` (headers, content, everything).

Comment: can you show us the php code where you set curl parameters?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this question is up to date or not. I can get the content normally using:

```
echo file_get_contents('http://fvbw.sm-u.de/index.php?seite=game&game=568');
```

Comment: Yeah, this is actually working for the above page. Additionally using a stream context even let me pass cookies to access password protected pages.